macOS: How to deal with [INSERT] key in midnight commander?
When browsing with Midnight Commander sometimes I want to copy something from its interface. Let's say the name of a file. For this, I press shift + f6. Now a dialog opens with the name of the file in an editable text entry control, so you can select the whole name and theoretically also copy it. The problem is: control + c won't work it would have to be the command for Linux shift+insert but my Mac doesn’t have an insert key.
Summary: I want to be able to copy and paste from the MC interface but control + c doesn’t work. That's OK because it should be shift + insert but no insert key exists on Mac. How can I deal with this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
